# Solving a simple equation of Allelic richness (diversity) [Population genetics]

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

Dear Math SE Community,

I would like to manually calculate the following equation on my simplified data. First, this is my data:

I have two sample (A and B) and for this two samples I have 3 loci. Each locus has two alleles, either coded as '0' or '1'. One locus has two missing alleles, I coded them as '-1'.
[Please look at the table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Y4AD.png)

I would like to calculate the Equation (1) in the following publication:

El Mousadik, A., & Petit, R. J. (1996). High level of genetic differentiation for allelic richness among populations of the argan tree [Argania spinosa (L.) Skeels] endemic to Morocco. Theoretical and Applied Genetics, 92(7), 832–839. doi:10.1007/bf00221895
[Please look at the corresponding paragraph.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xccwL.png)

The equation look like this:$$\sum_{i}\left[1-\frac{\binom{n}{N-N_{i}}}{\binom{n}{N}}\right]$$

I want to calculate this **for each locus separately than average it** (this is how it should work if I'm right).

**For example, for the first locus (for the allele '0'):**
n is 2, N is 4, and N-Ni is 1 (if I consider the allele '0', there are 3 of them).
$\left[1-\frac{\binom{2}{4-1}}{\binom{2}{4}}\right]$

**For example, for the first locus (for the allele '1'):**
n is 2, N is 4, and N-Ni is 3 (if I consider the allele '1', there is 1 of them).
$\left[1-\frac{\binom{2}{4-3}}{\binom{2}{4}}\right]$

$$\left[1-\frac{\binom{2}{3}}{\binom{2}{4}}\right] + \left[1-\frac{\binom{2}{1}}{\binom{2}{4}}\right] = 
\left[1-\frac{0.3333333333333333}{0.0833333333333333}\right] + \left[1-\frac{2}{0.0833333333333333}\right] =
\left[-2.996...\right] + \left[-23.000...\right] = -25.996..$$

The problem is that I compared my result with different software implementing this equation and they give a different result. **One software give (FSTAT) give 1.500, another software (R package PopGenReport) give 1.428571.** So my result should be around this value.

**I have no idea what goes wrong in my calculation**. Please help me with this problem.

**UPDATE:**

I just realized that my calculation is wrong since the binomial coefficient cannot be calculated if the "upper" is smaller than the "lower", that case (I found on StackOverflow) the result will be zero. I made a mistake when I was using an online calculator which works incorrectly. After checking with WolframAlpha, I have realized that should be zero (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=ncr%282%2C4%29).

Also, I was able to calculate the correct values using a different equation. I post it here as an answer, maybe someone needs it.

Comment: What does $\binom{2}{4}$ mean?

Comment: @Moo it is the combination and it is an arrangement in which the order of the objects does not matter. But, it is incorrect in my calculation, there is a mistake in it. I'm writing an update to the question now...

Comment: Does this mean you now have the correct results?

Comment: @Moo yes, just recently posted. :)

Answer (score 1):

To calculate Allelic Richness (diversity) I used the very original formula published by Hurlbert (1971).
Reference: Hurlbert, S. H. (1971). The nonconcept of species diversity: a critique and alternative parameters. Ecology, 52(4), 577-586.

[image: The corresponding paragraph can be found here.]

This seems to calculate is slightly differently, but matches exactly with the result of hierefstat (R package).

Using equation (13), from above, the calculation is the following:
$$\left[1-\frac{\binom{4-1}{2}}{\binom{4}{2}}\right] + \left[1-\frac{\binom{4-3}{2}}{\binom{4}{2}}\right] = 
\left[1-\frac{3}{6}\right] + \left[1-\frac{0}{6}\right] =
\left[0.5\right] + \left[1\right] = 1.5$$

For genetic data, my variables were the following:
N is the number of genes, so this is all the alleles for the given loci. This was 4.
n is the number of alleles. We have two, what we investigated. So n was 2.

First, I had to calculate it for the '0' allele, I had 3 of those. After for the '1' allele, I had 1 of that. Last, just summed it up.